# ScrollView not scrolling till end of the layout

Tags: android

I am trying to implement scrollview but my ScrollView not scrolling till end of the layout I tried all the steps suggested till now in stackoverflow but failed.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/parentLin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="hello"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/apul_textview_textviewtitle_textsize" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollMe"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_scrollview_scrollme_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:fillViewport="true"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinUserData"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fup_linearlayout_linuserdata_marginbottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fup_linearlayout_linuserdata_marginleft"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fup_linearlayout_linuserdata_marginright"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_linearlayout_linuserdata_margintop"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FirstNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_firstname_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_firstname_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="First Name *"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_firstname_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/LastNameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Last Name *"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EmailEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_emailedittext_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_emailedittext_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_emailedittext_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/WebsiteEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_website_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_website_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Website"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_website_paddingleft"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/RoleEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Role *"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_lastname_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/CountryEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_country_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_country_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Country"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_country_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/CityEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_city_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_city_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="City"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_city_paddingleft"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/AddressEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_address_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_address_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_address_paddingleft"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_ll_height"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_ll_margintop"
                    >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/phone1_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fup_spinner_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_spinner_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_phone"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_spinner_margintop"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fup_spinner_marginright"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/Phone1EditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_phone_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_margintop"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Phone1"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_phone_paddingleft"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_ll_height"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_ll_margintop">
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/phone2_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fup_spinner_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_spinner_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_phone"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_spinner_margintop"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fup_spinner_marginright"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/Phone2EditText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_phone2_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="Phone2"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_margintop"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_phone2_paddingleft"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_ll_height"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_ll_margintop">
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/fax_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/fup_spinner_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_spinner_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_phone"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_spinner_margintop"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fup_spinner_marginright"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/FaxEditText"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_fax_height"
                        android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_margintop"
                        android:hint="Fax"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_fax_paddingleft"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userProfessions"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_textview_userprofession_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_textview_userprofession_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_textview_userprofession_paddingleft"
                    android:text="Profession"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_textview_userprofession_textsize" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/UserDescEditText"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fup_edittext_userdesc_height"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fup_edittext_userdesc_margintop"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_box"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="User Description"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fup_edittext_userdesc_paddingleft"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fup_commontextview_textsize"
                    android:inputType="none"/>




            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The last edit text is being half displayed.After adding Scroll View code in Activity, padding bottom in XML of scroll view it is still not working
    Please help.

Comment: Your code is perfectly running ...what you want?

Comment: "After adding Scroll View code in Activity", can you post this java code?